# Changing text selection colour in footer only

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, footer

I'm looking for a way to change the text selection colour in the footer so that it is different for the selection colour elsewhere. Selection colour on the site as a whole is `#fff200`, whereas the text is `#241f51`, I would like to be able to change the selection colour in the footer only, to be the opposite to the rest of the site, so that when text is selected in the footer the background becomes blue (#241f51) and the text becomes yellow (#fff200). Is there anyway I can do this using css, or any other method for that matter?

I have absolutely no clue how to sort this out, and i only have a slight clue as to what i'm doing as a whole when it comes to websites. I'm building in Wordpress using a theme/site builder called BeTheme.

Thank you in advance for any help.

See photo for example from my site.

[image: See photo for example from my site]

Selection colour on the site as a whole is `#fff200`, whereas the text is `#241f51`, I'm trying to reverse this for the footer so that selected text has a nice contrast to the footer background colour

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like this?

```
::selection{
 background-color:yourColor;
}
footer ::selection{
 background-color:otherColor;
}
```

This one worked for me pretty well actually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can target the pseudo elements of specific sections and override the default styles (added compatibility for certain Mozilla browsers). Replace "footer" with the specific wrapper class or tag for your footer. Example:

```
        ::-moz-selection {
            background: #fff200;
        }
        ::selection {
            background: #fff200;
        }

        .footer ::-moz-selection {
            background: #241f51;
            color: #fff200;
        }
        .footer ::selection {
            background: #241f51;
            color: #fff200;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this but i can't seem to get it to work quite yet. I'll have to try a bit more.